# element only enabled while app. is running

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core

i am working on a GPS app in VS2015 UWP xaml app for my raspberry pi 2 running windows 10. When i debug the app on my local pc it runs as it should. When i run the app on my remote pc (RPi2) I can not see the map element. the buttons and text boxes appear, but no map. I have tried to make the app the default app on my raspberry pi and still no map. the only thing i can think of at this time is the lack of the GPS ( still waiting for it in t e mail) may be the reason why the map is not shown.  This is the same message that is shown when the mapcontrol is added to the page. Has anyone else ran into this issue while working with the mapcontrol for a rpi2 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are speaking of the message as i'm strongly assuming "this element is enabled only when the application is running" ... i had the same issue some months ago.

It turned out that it seems to be a bug, see ... https://connect.microsoft.com/windowsembeddedIoT/feedback/details/1415625/mapcontrol

It looks like the issue is solved with Windows IoT Build 10.0.10556.0 but i haven't verified it for now.

Regards
Tom